# Convert the values in .csv file to json format in a data weave based on the parameter in lookup function which is calling from another data weave

Tags: mule, dataweave

How to use the lookup function in data weave(1.0) which calls a flow with some parameters. Flow functionality is to convert the values in the .csv file to JSON based on the parameter in the lookup function.

Comment: Please provide example code of what you've tried, why you think it didn't work, what the output of, error messages if any, assumptions, etc. Hard to help you with the info you've provided aside from just pointing you to the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lookup fucntion docs are here:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/dataweave-language-introduction

You pass in the payload as the second parameter as a Map (object):

```
%dw 1.0 %output application/json
--- 

{   a: lookup("mySecondFlow",{b:"Hello"}) }
```

Here is a Mule flow that can accept this object with the 'b' key:

```
<flow name="mySecondFlow">
    <set-payload doc:name="Set Payload" value="#[payload.b + ' world!' ]"/>
</flow>
```

This example will produce this output:

```
{
  "a": "Hello world!"
}
```